# Стоит ли писать приложение на Meteor?

Tags: meteor

Привет! Небольшой вопрос, стоит ли начинать писать приложение на Meteor? Жив ли он или скорее мертв? Текущая версия 1.5.1 на сколько я знаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно жив, зайдите на [гитхаб](https://github.com/meteor/meteor) и посмотрите сами.

Писать приложение на Meteor стоит если вам нужно именно динамическое приложение, где постоянно идет работать с данными из БД, а не сайт вроде блога или новостного портала.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ))